# Understanding ActiveRecord::Base class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

While browsing ActiveRecord source code I found :

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
```

I did not understand how a class name can be like `ActiveRecord::Base`
Please explain it for me, I am not getting the concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ActiveRecord` is actually a Ruby [Module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html), which is originally defined similarly to:

```
module ActiveRecord
  # contents of module
end
```

Modules provide a namespace for classes and constants to be defined in, meaning classes can be defined inside modules, as `ActiveRecord::Base` is. So this is the same as

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    # contents of class
  end
end
```

In general, the `::` operator is used for namespace resolution, for referencing constants within namespaces. Technically, any variable beginning with a capital letter is a constant, so `Base` is a constant whose value is the class itself! And if there was a constant named `FOO` defined within `ActiveRecord` as follows:

```
module ActiveRecord
  FOO = "foo"
end
```

then its fully-qualified variable name would be `ActiveRecord::FOO`.

Comment: I think now I understand it, the line I reffered class ActiveRecord::Base  is openclass , right ?

Comment: Yes, `class ActiveRecord::Base` is shorthand for `module ActiveRecord; class Base`, and it "opens" the class so you can define methods within it.